# Speak in games via the Kinect with Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, kinect

Is it possible to hear / speak to lobby chat and my teammates mid-game via the Kinect? I'm not wearing headphones and I'm not in a party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided you have your settings to allow your kinect to be used as a chat device.

Make sure to run the kinect calibration routine first though, otherwise it won't do a good job filtering game sounds and so other people will hear your game in their headsets as well as your voice.

Comment: I have run that calibration. When I attempt to speak in lobby chat, no one responds and my mic indicator does not light up.

Comment: One gotcha is that everyone signed into the system has to have their settings to allow chat communication via the kinect as well, not sure if that's your problem though.

Comment: If it were working on my end, shouldn't the mic indicator light up when I speak?

Comment: If you mean the mic indicator in the party snap, then yes. Oh, by "signed into the system" I mean the physical xbox you're using, that may not have been clear in my comment.